# Guardar el contenido de un JTable en archivo .txt

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un código que inserta información referente a un autómata en un JTabla de 3 columnas, por lo que en el archivo .txt debería de aparecer, en cada fila del archivo, esos 3 datos como mínimo.El siguiente código me inserta el primer dato, pero falta por insertar los otros 2.¿Cuál puede ser el problema? Gracias.
Mi código es el siguiente:

private void guardaTabla(){
try {

```
        String sucursalesCSVFile = "D:\\/DatosTabla.txt";
        BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sucursalesCSVFile ));
        
        bfw.write("** AUTÓMATA ** ");
        bfw.write("\nEstados Totales: " + vistaEscribirAFD.jTextField1NodosTotalesAFD.getText());
        bfw.write("\nTransiciones del AFD: \n");
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getRowCount(); i++) //realiza un barrido por filas.
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getRowCount();j++) //realiza un barrido por columnas.
            {
                
                bfw.write((String)(vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getValueAt(i,j)));
                if (j < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getColumnCount() -1) { //agrega separador "," si no es el ultimo elemento de la fila.
                    bfw.write(",");
                }
            }
            bfw.newLine(); //inserta nueva linea.
        }

        bfw.close(); //cierra archivo!
        System.out.println("El archivo fue salvado correctamente!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Ocurrio un problema al salvar el archivo!" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás recorriendo la tabla completa para cada fila. Esto hace que solo se escriba el primer elemento de cada fila.

debes recorrer las columnas para cada fila:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getRowCount(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0 ; j < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                
        bfw.write((String)(vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getValueAt(i,j)));
        if (j < vistaEscribirAFD.jTable1AFDTeclado.getColumnCount() -1) {
            bfw.write(",");
        }
    }
    bfw.newLine();
}
```